# Improve performance in slow query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance

How can I improve the following query, since (in my opinion) it takes more time than it should, and I think I'm missing something in terms of query optimization(the query takes around 1.0-1.4 seconds):

```
SELECT  
    DISTINCT a."adId",ct.distance AS distance,a.title,a.link,a.excerpt,a.employer,a."createdAt",a.location, count(*) OVER() AS counted 
FROM  
    ad a 
JOIN 
    ads_industries ai ON ai."adId" = a."adId"  
JOIN( 
    SELECT  
        ci."cityId", 
        earth_box( ll_to_earth( 33.97, -118.24 ), 32186.8) @> ll_to_earth(ci.lat, ci.lon) AS distance 
    FROM 
        city ci 
    WHERE  
        earth_box( ll_to_earth( 33.97, -118.24 ), 32186.8) @> ll_to_earth(ci.lat, ci.lon) 
) AS ct ON ct."cityId" = a."cityId" 
WHERE 
    ai."industryId" in( 28,18,31,33,24,2,29,32,22,14,25 ) AND 
    a."createdAt" BETWEEN '2017-11-14 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-18 22:24:51' 
ORDER BY distance DESC,a."createdAt" DESC  
LIMIT  10 OFFSET 0;
```

This is what explain analyze shows: https://explain.depesz.com/s/YRfO
[image]

**ad** table:

```
     Column     |              Type              |                      Modifiers                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 adId           | integer                        | not null default nextval('"ad_adId_seq"'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 cityId         | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 title          | character varying(255)         | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 description    | text                           | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 link           | character varying(255)         | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 employer       | character varying(100)         | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 location       | character varying(100)         | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 excerpt        | character(191)                 | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 expirationDate | date                           | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 createdAt      | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 updatedAt      | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 lexemsvector   | tsvector                       |                                                     | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "ad_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("adId")
    "linkIdx" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (link)
    "cityIdIdx" btree ("cityId")
    "textsearchidx" gin ("cityId", lexemsvector)
Triggers:
    tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ad FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('lexemsvector', 'pg_catalog.english', 'title', 'description')
```

Table has 1578966 records( 10 GB in size ).

**ads_industries** table:

```
**ads_industries** table:
   Column   |   Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
------------+----------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 adId       | integer  | not null  | plain   |              | 
 industryId | smallint | not null  | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "adToIndustryIdx" btree ("industryId", "adId")
```

The table has 1782162 records( 62MB in size ).

**city** table:

```
  Column   |              Type              |                        Modifiers                        | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 cityId    | integer                        | not null default nextval('"city_cityId_seq"'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 stateId   | smallint                       | not null                                                | plain    |              | 
 name      | character varying(50)          | not null                                                | extended |              | 
 zipCode   | character(5)                   | not null                                                | extended |              | 
 lat       | double precision               | not null default '0'::double precision                  | plain    |              | 
 lon       | double precision               | not null default '0'::double precision                  | plain    |              | 
 visible   | boolean                        | not null                                                | plain    |              | 
 createdAt | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null                                                | plain    |              | 
 updatedAt | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null                                                | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "city_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("cityId")
    "cityGeolocIdx" gist (ll_to_earth(lat, lon))
    "zipCodeIdx" btree ("zipCode")
```

The city table has 50203 records(5 MB in size).

As I understands from the EXPLAIN, the problem seems to be in the ads_industries join, despite using "Index Only Scan".

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 2
RAM: 4GB
PostgreSQL version 9.6.4 with default settings.

Comment: don't use `earthdistance`.

Comment: Why do you think that's the problem? It seems that part is being executed pretty fast?

Comment: Why are you using `DISTINCT`? You're trying to find the 10 furtherest ads inside the city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this line from you plan:

> Index Cond: ((ai."industryId" = ANY ('{28,18,31,33,24,2,29,32,22,14,25}'::integer[])) AND (ai."adId" = a."adId"))

I think having an index on `ads_industries ("adId", "industryId")` might help.  Either in addition to, or instead of, the one with those columns reversed.

It is generally best to have the more specific column first, and a simple equality test is likely to be more specific than a `=ANY` test.

Comment: And the query execution time dropped to 0.2 seconds. Thanks you so much, @jjanes.

Answer (score 0):

Either way, I'd drop `DISTINCT` it would be weird for you to ever have 3 duplicate rows given this, if I'm reading it right. I'm also curious to 
 know why you need the `count(*) OVER ()` in the app -- there is a high cost of that.

## Use PostGIS

I'll assume you're on SRID 4326.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
BEGIN;
  ALTER TABLE city ADD COLUMN geog GEOGRAPHY(point,4326);
  UPDATE city
  SET geog = ST_MakePoint(long,lat)
    WHERE long<>0
    AND lat <> 0;
  CREATE INDEX ON city USING gist(geog);
  ALTER TABLE city
    DROP COLUMN lat,
    DROP COLUMN long;
COMMIT;
```

Then change to,

```
SELECT a."adId",
  ct.distance AS distance,
  a.title,
  a.link,
  a.excerpt,
  a.employer,
  a."createdAt",
  a.location,
  count(*) OVER() AS counted 
FROM ad a 
JOIN ads_industries ai ON ai."adId" = a."adId"  
JOIN city AS ct
  ON ct."cityId" = a."cityId"
  AND ST_Intersects(
    ST_MakePoint(33.97,-118.24)::geography,
    ct.geom,
    1609.34 * 20
  )
WHERE
    ai."industryId" IN ( 28,18,31,33,24,2,29,32,22,14,25 )
    AND a."createdAt" BETWEEN '2017-11-14 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-18 22:24:51'
ORDER BY
  ST_MakePoint(33.97,-118.24)::geography <=> ct.geom DESC,
  a."createdAt" DESC  
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I use the `count(*) OVER ()` to count all of the results, since I only get limited set of the rows. As for the `distinct`,  one ad can have multiple industries, so only one ad needs to be in the result set. I'll try your solution, but the EXPLAIN shows the slowest part of the query to be the `Index Only Scan` on `ads_industries`. Btw isn't using PostGis for a simple radius search an overkill?